# Is there a way to force Vue to prefer the inherited class?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have a component where I want Vue to ignore the class that was already there and use the inherited class instead. But only if the class is of the same type as the inherited class. Here is an example of what I mean:

I have a button component like this

MyButton.vue

```
<button class="text-sm font-roboto justify-center text-red-500">
  <slot></slot>
</button>
```

Then in my project I would like to use `MyButton` component but I want to override the `justify-center` and `text-red-500` classes with my own, for example like this:

```
<MyButton class="justify-start text-gray-100">click me</MyButton>
```

The result is this rendered button:

```
<button class="text-sm font-roboto justify-center text-red-500 justify-start text-gray-100">
  click me
</button>
```

The problem is that HTML prioritizes the class `justify-center` and `justify-start` class is ignored. I would like Vue to be smart enough that it understands Tailwind classes and if it sees that there was `justify-center` originally and now I pass in `justify-start` then it should remove `justify-center` and add `justify-start`.

I also want it to do this for all Tailwind classes. If it sees that there was originally a `text-....` class then it should remove that and replace it with the inherited class. Same for `fonts` and `colors` and `shadows` etc.

**So the result would be like this:**

```
<button class="text-sm font-roboto justify-start text-gray-100">
  click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have two options:

1. for *alignment*, *color*, and ... you can define props with the default classname values:

```
props: {
  alignment: 'start',
  // other props
},
```

and bind these props to the CSS class and use these there.

2. You can use vue directives:

```
Vue.directive('tailwind', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    let currentClasses = el.classList;
    for (let i = 0; i < currentClasses.length; i++) {
      let className = currentClasses[i];
      if (className.startsWith('text-') || className.startsWith('justify-') || className.startsWith('font-')) {
        el.classList.remove(className);
      }
    }
  },
  update: function(el, binding, vnode) {
     let newClasses = binding.value.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < newClasses.length; i++) {
      let className = newClasses[i];
      if (className.startsWith('text-') || className.startsWith('justify-') || className.startsWith('font-')) {
        el.classList.add(className);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And you can use it in this way:

```
<button v-tailwind="class" class="text-sm font-roboto justify-center text-red-500">
  <slot></slot>
</button>

<MyButton class="justify-start text-gray-100">click me</MyButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it by using a 3rd party library `tailwind-merge`

```js
<template>
    <button :class="buttonClass">
        <slot></slot>
        <i class="text-base text-gray-400 font-normal">
        class="{{ buttonClass }}"</i>
    </button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { computed, useAttrs } from 'vue'
    import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

    const attrs = useAttrs()

    const buttonClass = computed(() => {
        return twMerge('font-bold text-3xl justify-center text-red-500 ', attrs.class)
    })
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export default {
        inheritAttrs: false
    }
</script>
```